# API Json response to C# Object with capital case properties first letter

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I've made an API where after an Entity Framework elaboration I send an object serialized in Json.

**My Object:**

```
public class Package
{
    public int Items { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double? Weight { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string PackageType { get; set; }
}
```

The problem start when after recieve it (Xamarin app) the Json have the first letter lowercase, but I want deserialize it in the exact same class and it can't because the class have properties in capitalcase (C# standard).
Now I'm using a horrible 'helper' class that have the properties in lowercase for translating it.

Any idea how to handle this and send the Json directly with capital case first letter?

**Edit**

I use **ASP.NET web API Core** and **Newtonsoft.Json**

In Xamarin app I use **System.Text.Json**

Comment: Are you using asp.net web api core?

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify it... 

I use asp.net web api core and 
I use Newtonsoft.Json in the core API and System.Text.Json in Xamarin app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET Core encodes all JSON properties names in camel case, to match JSON conventions (see the [announcement of the change on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194)).

If you want to keep the C# conventions, you need to change the default JSON serializer.

In your `Startup.cs`, configure the MVC part like this (ASP.Net Core 3.0):

```cs
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        // don't serialize with CamelCase (see https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194)
        jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new JsonContractResolver();
    });
```

For ASP.NET Core 2.0 :

```cs
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // don't serialize with CamelCase (see https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194)
        jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

Answer (score 19):

You have to change the default property naming policy on the json serialization options.

By default it's set to camel case but if you set it to `null`, the property names are to remain unchanged (or remain as you wrote on your class).

Simply add this to your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```