# asp.net core does not respect case sensitivity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i have this controller method that return an array of objects

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<List<AllClientsDataModelDb>>> GetAll() 
    {
        var  ReturnValue = new List<AllClientsDataModelDb>();
        ReturnValue = await Clda.GetClients(new { cm = 1 });
        return (ReturnValue);
    }
```

here is the code of AllClientsDataModelDb class

```
  public class AllClientsDataModelDb
    {
        public long IDCLIENT { get; set; }
        public string CL_CODE { get; set; }
        public string CL_NOM { get; set; }
        public string CL_ADRESSE { get; set; }
        public string CL_CODEPOS { get; set; }
        public string CL_VILLE { get; set; } = null;
        public int CL_ETATCOMPTE { get; set; }
        public int CL_AlerteCompta { get; set; }
    }
```

but the result of that method (in browser) does not respect the case sensitivity of the class properties
Example :

```
[{"idclient":1,"cL_CODE":"1","cL_NOM":"EUROPEQUIPEMENTMysql","cL_ADRESSE":"ModifSoft","cL_CODEPOS":"44","cL_VILLE":"STDENIS","cL_ETATCOMPTE":1,"cL_AlerteCompta":0},

{"idclient":2,"cL_CODE":"2","cL_NOM":"A UTOMATISMES-SERVICESzzzz","cL_ADRESSE":null,"cL_CODEPOS":"97420","cL_VILLE":"LEPORT","cL_ETATCOMPTE":1,"cL_AlerteCompta":0},
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You're not really doing anything wrong.  The default serializer settings lowercase the first letter to keep with JSON conventions.  You _can_ override the default, see the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154562/1030169

Comment: @jmoerdyk no it does not , look at IDCLIENT for example its lower everything not only the first letter

Comment: @jmoerdyk and i'm using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: @jmoerdyk it didn't work

Comment: Please show your attempt at overriding the JSON naming convention.

Comment: Also, you said in the title that you're using ASP.NET Core, but your question tags the old ASP.NET and ASP.NET Web API frameworks. What actual framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own Json Profile Formatter by inheriting from JsonOutputFormatter.

```
public class PascalCaseJsonProfileFormatter : JsonOutputFormatter
{
    public PascalCaseJsonProfileFormatter() : base(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() }, ArrayPool<char>.Shared)
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse
     ("application/json;profile=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase\""));
    }
}
```

Then modify your `Startup.cs` file's `ConfigureServices` Method like this.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new PascalCaseJsonProfileFormatter());
    });
```

Try this, it should work.